# migrate from apache to nginx : 403 directory index of is forbidden

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to migrate my apache server to nginx and am therefore converting my apache vhost to nginx.
However, I'm ran into this 403 directory index of '' is forbidden and struggle to find out what the problem is. 
I suppose that I have something wrong in my nginx conf but don't know what :

```
server {
        listen 8000;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        root /var/www/html/domain;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index app.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
        }

        location ~/\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        index app.php?method=index&lang=;

        location / {
            if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^/(en|fr|de)$ /app.php?method=index&lang=$1 break;
            }
        }
}
```

The server is under ubuntu on an AWS EC2 instance and the app is a very light php app that's built without any framework or whatsoever.

Comment: both nginx user and fpm user needs access to /var/www/html/domain. check the permission of the directory, which uid nginx run with and with uid php-fpm run with. check the permission on the php files too

Comment: I checked that and everything is fine :/

Comment: next step (actually has to be the first one) - check the log file for errors

Comment: It's in the logs that I found : "403 directory index of is forbidden"

Comment: So you have to check the permission on the directory index

Comment: even with a chmod 777 it keeps returning this error

Comment: look at the php-fpm dconfiguration files. it runs with specific user and socket permissions

Comment: everything seems to be fine. So there is definitely nothing wrong in my nginx config that I copied on the post above ?

Comment: it probably permission issue, and it could be in the file system, in php-fpm, or in nginx (which not seems to be the problem here). you can receive access denied if nginx doesn't have permissions on a top dir. for instance, if /var or /var/www or /var/www/html doenst hav access permission to the world or to the user that is running nginx/php-fpm - you will receive 'forbidden' error